# Cambiar texto a botones luego de ser presionados

Tags: javascript, html

agradecer por el apoyo brindado hasta ahora, son de gran ayuda en este mundo de continuo aprendizaje.
ahora me encuentro en un dilema, quiero que mis DIV en forma de botones cambien de nombre cada vez que son presionados, pero solo logro que cambie el primero de los botones, aqui dejo mi codigo:

```
// Calls for clipboard.js
var clipboard = new ClipboardJS(".btn");

 clipboard.on("success", function(e) {
 e.clearSelection();
 });

 clipboard.on("error", function(e) {
  console.error("Action:", e.action);
  console.error("Trigger:", e.trigger);
 });

 function FbotonOn() {
  var uno = document.getElementById('btn');
 if (uno.textContent == 'Copiar Codigo') 
    uno.textContent = 'Codigo Copiado';
 }
```

esa es mi funcion de copiar y pegar y cambiar de nombre al DIV que uso como boton.
aqui dejo el html:

```
                              <div><span class="btn" id="btn"  onclick="FbotonOn()" 
           data-clipboard-text="${post.codigo}">Copiar Codigo</span></div>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que el problema es que estás usando el mismo ID para todos los botones. El ID debe ser único para cada elemento del documento, así que si tienes varios botones, debes asignarles distintos IDs.

Una opción es usar una clase en lugar de un ID para todos tus botones y hacer referencia a ellos a través de la clase en lugar del ID en tu función FbotonOn().

Por ejemplo, en lugar de:

```
<div><span class="btn" id="btn" onclick="FbotonOn()" data-clipboard-text="${post.codigo}">Copiar Codigo</span></div>
```

Podrías usar:

```
<div><span class="btn boton" onclick="FbotonOn(this)" data-clipboard-text="${post.codigo}">Copiar Codigo</span></div>
```

Y en tu función, hacer referencia al botón presionado a través del parámetro "this":

```
function FbotonOn(boton) {
  if (boton.textContent == 'Copiar Codigo') 
  boton.textContent = 'Codigo Copiado';
}
```

Comment: Excelente, gracias